# spring json serialization issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux

I am unable to get is_secure object attribute in json response, what is wrong with this code ?

```
@Configuration
class RouterConfiguration( ) {
    @Bean
    fun testRoutes(testHandler: TestHandler) = coRouter {
        GET("/test", testHandler::testFunction)
    }
}
data class TestClass(
    val is_secure: Int? = 1,
    val xyz: String?
)
@Component
class TestHandler{
    suspend fun testFunction(request: ServerRequest): ServerResponse =
        ServerResponse.ok().bodyValueAndAwait(TestClass(1,"abc"))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is` prefixed fields (with camelCase or snake_case pattern) are only serialized if they are of type Boolean. You can find more details about it [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/337).

If you wish to keep the `is` prefix, you may do so by using `@get` use-site target. Just use `@get:JsonProperty("is_secure")` on the `is_secure` field and it should do.

Comment: Thanks, i tried searching multiple place, but did not find anything.

Comment: Yes, Agreed that the problem itself in not very obvious looking at it. The main reason for this behaviour is that the serializations are in accordance to Java Beans spec §8.3.2 https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/ . According to it, is-getters are valid only for boolean properties.